# Render Bitmap in UWP with MVVM

Tags: xaml, uwp, toolkit, rendertargetbitmap

In my code behind I used to render the bitmap from my grid with `RenderTargetBitmap`.

```
var renderBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
await renderBitmap.RenderAsync(UIElement);
```

I want to use the MVVM pattern but now the `RenderTargetBitmap` class does not work anymore.

Now I'm trying to use the WinRT XAML Toolkit - Composition

```
var gridBitmap = await WriteableBitmapRenderExtensions.Render(Grid);
```

but then I get this error: Message `"Unable to expand length of this stream beyond its capacity."` string

Is there a other way to render this in MVVM? Maybe with `SharpDX`? Or Iam doing anything wrong?

Comment: This is actually somewhat of an ideological/philosophical question if you consider the Bitmap data to be a "view" or not. Ideally we'd know more about the nature of your application.

Comment: Also, note that MVVM does not mean that you should never use Code-behind. There is nothing wrong with using code-behind logic - it's just that the code-behind logic should only be concerned with "the view" and nothing else, like business rules or database queries, for example - so performing operations on bitmaps in your code-behind may be totally correct for your application.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that rendering a UI element into a bitmap is really not a task for view model, as it is very View-specific. In this case then I would see no harm in putting this code in the page's code behind and making it possible to trigger this method from the view-model.

Depending on the MVVM framework you are using, you could trigger the function in different ways. First would be to make the page implement an interface like `IRenderGrid` with this one method, then add a new method to the view-model that will take `IRenderGrid` as parameter and store the instance for later use, and then in `OnNavigatedTo` of the page call this view model method.

```cs
interface IRenderGrid
{
   Bitmap RenderGrid();
}

class MainViewModel
{
   ...

   private IRenderGrid _renderGrid;
   public void RegisterRenderGrid( IRenderGrid renderGrid )
   {
       _renderGrid = renderGrid;
   }
}

class MainPage : Page, IRenderGrid
{
   ...   

   protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
   {
       base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
       var viewModel = DataContext as MainViewModel;//get the view model
       viewModel.RegisterRenderGrid( this );
   }

   public Bitmap RenderGrid()
   {
       var renderBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
       await renderBitmap.RenderAsync(Grid);
   }
}
```

Of course the problem is that if your view models reside in a different assembly, you will not have access to `Bitmap` there, so you will have to wrap it in some custom type.

Alternative approach to triggering the page's method would be to use a messenger, which many MVVM frameworks offer. In such case you would subscribe to a trigger message in the view and react to such message by executing the rendering and then pass the result to the view model either with another message or through a public method.

Comment: Thank you. I already thought about it. I dont use a framework I wrote the pattern by hand. I will try your code today!